# How can i check if a word is in dictionary taking the user input that inserted into the array

Tags: arrays, validation, dictionary, input

I've been trying to figure out, the best way to tackle this problem.

The problem Im stuck on is where I need to take the user input(word) and put it in the array and try to confirm/validate if all the letters they've use are in the char array(generates 10 random letters)(letterpool) then check again if the word they've use are valid from the dictionary.

I have a dictionary called "dict.txt" which contains 80k words in lowercase
dictionary. i need somehow take the input(uppercase) and be able to locate the word of the dictionary in lowercase

I hope you guys can help me, Programming language Java
Thanks in advance!

Eric

Comment: Please first try yourself and then come back with a specific question.

Comment: Please add your code to your question. We will be happy to help you from that point.

Comment: @TDG the code is now in the question. thank you so much, ive been stuck in couple of weeks and no luck

Comment: @JFMeier im having a trouble accessing the dictionary.words (has all the words)

Answer (score 0):

I'd create a `HashMap<Character, Integer>` and put the random letters in the map.

```
map.put(letter, 0);
```

Then I'd go through the letters from your word and do this

```
Integer value = map.get(letterFromYourWord);
if(value == null){
  //raise exception because the letter from your word is not in your random array
} else {
  // increment the value from the map
  map.put(letterFromYourWord, value++);
}
```

then go through the map and check if the values are not 0. If there is one with value 0 then your word is not used in your random array.

with this implementation you can extend easily more functionalities, like counting the letters which are used in your word...

Answer (score 0):

For the validWord function I would suggest making use of the binary search for sorted arrays. Something along those lines:

```
   static boolean validWord(String word, final char[] letters)
   {
       char[] lettersCopy = letters.clone();
       Arrays.sort(lettersCopy); // sort so we can use binary search           
       for(char c : word.toCharArray())
       {
          if(Arrays.binarySearch(lettersCopy, c) < 0) //char c from word not in letterPool?
          {
              return false;
          }
       }
       return true;       
   }
```

Then in your TRIALS loop you would just call it like this:

```
           if (validWord(input,letterPool))
           {
              System.out.println("Yes, the letters match");    
            }else {
              System.out.println("No");
           }
```

I am not sure which Dictionary class you are using there so I cannot help you with that.

Btw:
Arctigors answer using hashmaps is more cpu performant yet more heavy on the memory side. (O(n) instead of O(n*lb(m)))

Comment: Thank you man. about the dictionary, its on different class however i have a string array (public String[] words= null;) i need to inherit this to the main class to validate if a word is in dictionary